# Run a node virtually that can be accessed from different machines

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, cardano-node, ubuntu

I am trying to run a cardano node, however I am not sure of the best way to go about it. My goal is to create a cardano wallet through python on my own machine. I want to run a cardano node on a VM, and be able to give access to myself and others, so we can all connect to that same node. I was wondering if this is possible, and if so how to go about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a docker container setup on some cloud instance which is pretty quick to set up and cheap as well.

There is pretty good documentation available on how to set up a node.

See here:

- https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/
- https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node#docker-image